# Trying to put for loop in goroutine

Tags: go

I'm beginner trying to run two functions synchronously, I use waitGroup to wait for one of the function. The problem is that Go seems to ignore completely my for loop and prints packetsReceived = 0

```
func introducePacket(firstVortex chan string) {
    index := 1
    packetsSended := 0
    msg := strconv.Itoa(index) + " message"
    for packetsSended > 14 {
        select {
        case firstVortex <- msg:
            fmt.Println(msg)
            packetsSended++
        default:
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func receivePacket(wg *sync.WaitGroup, lastVortex chan string) {
    packetsReceived := 0
    fmt.Println("RECEIVE")
    for packetsReceived > 14 {
        select {
        case msg := <-lastVortex:
            fmt.Println(msg)
            packetsReceived++
        default:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(packetsReceived)
    defer wg.Done()
}


func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)

    vortexOne := make(chan string, 1)
    vortexThree := make(chan string, 1)

    go introducePacket(vortexOne)
    go receivePacket(&wg, vortexThree)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop doesn't execute because `packetsReceived>14` is false from the start. Perhaps you meant `for packetsRecieved <= 14`?

(And the same for `packetsSent`).

`for EXPR { ... }`  executes the body of the for loop while `EXPR` is true.

Comment: That is true... Thank you very much

Comment: but i think still this one is not going to work.